# Best approch to deploy web app on vps server?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, kotlin, docker-compose

I am trying to build my first web app based on an springboo kotlin backend and a vue js frontend with mysql as a db.

Everything is fine on my localmachine, but things get harder when I want to push it to prod.

To prod I am using docker files and docker compose to assemble everything.

However I am facing issues for the communication between my front end & back end.

Mostly ssl certificate management, https and domain name (cross dommain orgini error).

I am not here to solve this issues. My question is:

Would you rather stick to workink with docker containers even if I only have one vps for now ?

Or would it been "smarter" to run jar & vue js files directly on the server ?

Thank you for any advice.

Also I would be intressted in any good article / video you could have on the topic.

Regards